# What does `va_num` mean in this variadic macro?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, c99

It seems different compilers handle macros with varaible parameters slight differently.

For C99-compatible compilers, a special identifier `__VA_ARGS__` is used to represent the varaible parameter list:

```
#define MACRO_1(param1, ...) func(param1, __VA_ARGS__)
```

For GNU C compiler, a name can be given to the varaible parameter list:

```
#define MACRO_2(param1, args...) func(param1, args) // "args..." is the name
```

But I see below definition in ACPICA code:

```
#define uefi_call_wrapper(func, va_num, ...) func(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And a call to such macro is like this:

```
uefi_call_wrapper(BS->SetWatchdogTimer, 4, 0, 0x0, 0, NULL);
```

It seems like the C99 approach, but the `va_num` seems useless. Why it is defined?

### ADD 1  -  The complete definition of the macro

```
#ifdef USE_EFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER
#define __VA_NARG__(...)                        \
  __VA_NARG_(_0, ## __VA_ARGS__, __RSEQ_N())
#define __VA_NARG_(...)                         \
  __VA_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define __VA_ARG_N(                             \
  _0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,N,...) N
#define __RSEQ_N()                              \
  10, 9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0

#define __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX__(prefix,...)                  \
  __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX_N(prefix, __VA_NARG__(__VA_ARGS__))
#define __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX_N(prefix,nargs)        \
  __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX_N_(prefix, nargs)
#define __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX_N_(prefix,nargs)       \
  prefix ## nargs

/* Prototypes of EFI cdecl -> stdcall trampolines */

UINT64 efi_call0(void *func);
UINT64 efi_call1(void *func, UINT64 arg1);
UINT64 efi_call2(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2);
UINT64 efi_call3(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3);
UINT64 efi_call4(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4);
UINT64 efi_call5(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5);
UINT64 efi_call6(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5, UINT64 arg6);
UINT64 efi_call7(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5, UINT64 arg6, UINT64 arg7);
UINT64 efi_call8(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5, UINT64 arg6, UINT64 arg7,
                 UINT64 arg8);
UINT64 efi_call9(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                 UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5, UINT64 arg6, UINT64 arg7,
                 UINT64 arg8, UINT64 arg9);
UINT64 efi_call10(void *func, UINT64 arg1, UINT64 arg2, UINT64 arg3,
                  UINT64 arg4, UINT64 arg5, UINT64 arg6, UINT64 arg7,
                  UINT64 arg8, UINT64 arg9, UINT64 arg10);

/* Front-ends to efi_callX to avoid compiler warnings */

#define _cast64_efi_call0(f) \
  efi_call0(f)
#define _cast64_efi_call1(f,a1) \
  efi_call1(f, (UINT64)(a1))
#define _cast64_efi_call2(f,a1,a2) \
  efi_call2(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2))
#define _cast64_efi_call3(f,a1,a2,a3) \
  efi_call3(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3))
#define _cast64_efi_call4(f,a1,a2,a3,a4) \
  efi_call4(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4))
#define _cast64_efi_call5(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) \
  efi_call5(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
            (UINT64)(a5))
#define _cast64_efi_call6(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6) \
  efi_call6(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
            (UINT64)(a5), (UINT64)(a6))
#define _cast64_efi_call7(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) \
  efi_call7(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
            (UINT64)(a5), (UINT64)(a6), (UINT64)(a7))
#define _cast64_efi_call8(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8) \
  efi_call8(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
            (UINT64)(a5), (UINT64)(a6), (UINT64)(a7), (UINT64)(a8))
#define _cast64_efi_call9(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) \
  efi_call9(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
            (UINT64)(a5), (UINT64)(a6), (UINT64)(a7), (UINT64)(a8), \
            (UINT64)(a9))
#define _cast64_efi_call10(f,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10) \
  efi_call10(f, (UINT64)(a1), (UINT64)(a2), (UINT64)(a3), (UINT64)(a4), \
             (UINT64)(a5), (UINT64)(a6), (UINT64)(a7), (UINT64)(a8), \
             (UINT64)(a9), (UINT64)(a10))

/* main wrapper (va_num ignored) */

#define uefi_call_wrapper(func,va_num,...)                        \
  __VA_ARG_NSUFFIX__(_cast64_efi_call, __VA_ARGS__) (func , ##__VA_ARGS__)

#else

#define uefi_call_wrapper(func, va_num, ...) func(__VA_ARGS__)

#endif
```

Comment: It seems to be just a normal macro argument that simply isn't used in the macro expansion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But why? Someone tell me it's related to the VC6 compiler. But I still cannot see it through. Is it just a `hint` to the VC6 pre-processor so that VC6 can tell how many args there are. But I think it's really unncessary because the syntax already reveals that.

Comment: You can create a macro that takes *ten* arguments, but use none of them in the macro expansion. It's just what happens here, your macro invocation `uefi_call_wrapper(BS->SetWatchdogTimer, 4, 0, 0x0, 0, NULL)` results in the expansion `BS->SetWatchdogTimer(0, 0x0, 0, NULL)`. That's it. The `va_num` argument isn't used, it's discarded. Just because it's named with the `va_` prefix doesn't mean it has to be a special C symbol.

Comment: And by the way, is the `uefi_call_wrapper` macro defined inside some conditional compilation section? Is there perhaps some conditions where `uefi_call_wrapper` *does* use the `va_num` argument? Have you checked source control logs to see if it might have *been* used sometime in the past?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes. Let me post the complete conditional section.

Comment: Well the comment `/* main wrapper (va_num ignored) */` should explain it all I think... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`va_num` is just a normal parameter passed to the function, which the macro just ignores it.

Usage 1:

This kind of usage is usual when the macro is used across different compiler settings, in order to get the same function calling in all of them, but mapping to a different `func`, which may (or may not) support the `va_num` parameter. In this particular case, `func` may not support `va_num` parameter, so the macro just ignores it.

Usage 2:

May be used also to handle old code, making it easily portable to the new version of the macro.

Answering your question, the `va_num` parameter is not a special parameter. It is used just as any other parameter, and nothing to do with `__VA_ARGS__` or similar. The writer of the macro decided to give that name to that parameter, just to state that it should contain the number of arguments passed, but nothing fancier nor compiler raleted.

Comment: Yes, I just added a call sample to `uefi_call_wrapper`.

Comment: It might be, too, a remainder of an earlier version of the macro and is left for compatibility reasons...